# How to install angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have work to do in angular 5. But now angular 7 is already released, I am not sure how to install angular5 into my computer. Couple of months earlier I have been working in angular 6. Should I remove the current version installed ?

Can anybody tell me how to install angular5 and how to know if it's angular 5/6/7?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the angular version and it's dependencies version in `package.json` to use **v5** of the library. 
Make sure you have compatible versions in dependencies list. Also you don't need to depend on **angular-cli** to develop your project

Also when your app runs, you can see angular version attached to your DOM (in the app component). Or you can open your Dev tool in browser and inspect the root node of DOM, there you will find `ng-version` information.

You can also run `ng -v` after doing `npm install` to see the versions of the angular and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Angular cli 1.x creates Angular 5 project. Angular cli version 6 and 7 creates Angular 6 and 7 project respectively.

If you want to creates Angular 5 project from scratch, try this commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1
ng new my-project
```